# How to set CPU affinity to a process

Tags: 11.10, process

How can I set how many physical CPUs can a process use (CPU Affinity) before the process starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) :

```
taskset 0x03 your_command
```

will launch `your_command` on the cpus #0 and #1.